# Takes positions without overlapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method that creates objects and displays them on scene. The only problem is that the points I send to the created objects sometimes overlap, so the objects also overlap.

```
private IEnumerator doBallSpawn()
{
    while (currentBallsCount < maxBallsIndex)
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), -8f, 0f);

        ObjectSequence ball = Instantiate(BallSequence, pos, Quaternion.identity) as ObjectSequence;
        ball.setCurrentChildIndex(BallColorRandom.getRandom());

        Vector3 goPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), UnityEngine.Random.Range(MinY, MaxY));
        ball.transform.DOMove(goPosition, moveDuration);
        currentBallsCount++;
        ball.gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<SequenceMouseEvent>().MouseEvent += BallClickEvent;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

`goPosition` is the only thing I have to change, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects have colliders, you can use [Bounds.Intersect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Intersects.html) method to know if they overlap.